# JRXmlDataSource with queryString give no records

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with XML datasource for Jasper Reports. When i use `selectExpression` in `JRXmlDataSource` constructor, everything works, but when i use `queryString` in `.jrxml`, i get no records.

working example:

```
JRXmlDataSource ds2 = new JRXmlDataSource(new FileInputStream(dataSourceFile), "/pages/page");
```

not working example:

```
JRXmlDataSource ds1 = new JRXmlDataSource(new FileInputStream(dataSourceFile));

<jasperReport>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/pages/page]]>
    </queryString>
    ...
</jasperReport>
```

Data XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
    <page>
        <firstname>X</firstname>
        <lastname>Y</lastname>
    </page>
    <page>
        <firstname>Z</firstname>
        <lastname>V</lastname>
    </page>
    <page>
        <firstname>B</firstname>
        <lastname>S</lastname>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Did you check your report in `iReport` with attached datasource?

Comment: Strangely in iReport the same `queryString` embedded in `.jrxml` works. I do not understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found solution. Instead of passing a XML dataSource to `JasperFillManager`, it can be passed an XML document like below. Now XPath in `<queryString language="xPath">` inside `.jrxml` template works on passed document and that's it what i want.

```
Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(dataSourceFile));
params.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, document);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
```