# JasperReport XML Datasource without Xpath in java code

Tags: java, xpath, jasper-reports

I am writing Java code to render `jrxml` file(jasper reports) from `XML datasource` into `PDF` output, I am successfully able to generate reports.

However there is one problem, `jrxml`s report templates and xml data sources are uploaded to the system. When ever it needs to generate the report, dynamically template file and xml datasource is picked and rendered.
Issue is with the XPath, every xml datasource has its own hierarchy so is the `XPath`.

```
JRXmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource("C:/Mazhar Hassan/contact-ds.xml","/datasource/contacts");
```

Second parameter `"/datasource/contacts"` is XPATH used for report. It cant be fixed(hard coded), because I have other datasources as well `"/datasource/students"` or `"datasource/schools/teachers"` etc etc.

If I skip the second parameter nothing is rendered, It is like no records are retrieved (Invalid XPATH).

```
JRXmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource("C:/Mazhar Hassan/contact-ds.xml");
```

**Q : Is there a why to generate report correctly without specific xpath in java code, It should pick from the JRXML.**

```
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/datasource/contacts]]>
</queryString>
```

Comment: It may works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517045/jrxmldatasource-with-querystring-give-no-records

Comment: Have you tried using parameters? You might need to access them using the **$P!{...}** notation.

Comment: @KevalTrivedi Please add those line in an answer so that I can accept that and it will be helpful for others.